# Using bash to call Go and Python scripts

Tags: bash

I would like to find a way of creating a bash script (scripts.sh) which will execute different Python and Go scripts inside of itself.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="https://google.com"    
bash scripts.sh URL
```

which would append the URL parameter to all the scripts called inside the bash script itself.

Let's say I have 2 python scripts and 2 Go scripts to call within the bash with that same parameter coded-in.

```
python3 script1.py -u URL
python3 script2.py -d URL
goscript -domain URL
goscript2 -d URL
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some additional informations? Have you tried to insert the 4 lines in your bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Use the URL variable to call your other commands.  Like this, in a single script:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="https://google.com"    

python3 script1.py -u $URL
python3 script2.py -d $URL
goscript -domain $URL
goscript2 -d $URL
```

To call scripts.sh, you can do it like this:

```
./scripts.sh
```

---

If you want a wrapper script to define the URL value, you could to this:

- wrapper.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  URL="https://example.com"
  scripts.sh $URL
  ```
- scripts.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  URL="$1"

  python3 script1.py -u $URL
  python3 script2.py -d $URL
  goscript -domain $URL
  goscript2 -d $URL
  ```

Add to this some verifications (ex. number of arguments is ok, URL is a valid url format, ...).  What I posted is to demonstrate the idea, not a full "production" ready script.